# JS Data Always One Run Behind

Tags: javascript, php, discord, webhooks

I'm currently adding a function to my registration script to push a message to Discord with form submission information. The function works, however, the sendMessage() script's information is always sent using the data from the previous run. In other words, if a user registers, it only sends to Discord after the next registrant registers. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    //Define Fields
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $ref  = $_POST['ref'];
    $timestamp = time();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    echo "<script> sendMessage() </script>";

    }

?>

<script>
    function sendMessage() {
        
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/**excluded**");
            
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        
        
        var myEmbed = {
            author: {
                name: "NAME - Stats"
            },
            title: "NEW Registration ",
            description: "<?php echo $username ?> has secured their username and pre-registered for the NAME beta.",
            color: hexToDecimal("#7812A7"),
            image: {
                url: "https://example.com/assets/gif/pre-registration.gif"
            },
            footer: {
                text: "Pre-registrations are now open!  • Boost your queue position by referring",
                icon_url: "https://example.com/assets/img/branding/logo_icon_outlined.png"
            }
        }
        
        var params = {
            username: "User Update",
            embeds: [ myEmbed ]
        }

        // function that converts a color HEX to a valid Discord color
        function hexToDecimal(hex) {
            return parseInt(hex.replace("#",""), 16)
        }
        
        request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
    </script>
```